# phpMailer not working after being hosted

Tags: php, timeout, phpmailer

phpMailer script works fine on localhost but once uploaded on 000webhost.com it gives me this error message:

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 
The following From address failed: abc@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being connected         Mailer Error: The following From address failed: abc@gmail.com : Called Mail() without being    connected
```

here is my script:

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php          if not already loaded

////////extracting form data from POST/////////

$course = $_REQUEST["Course__2"];
$receiver_name = $_REQUEST["Name__1"];
$receiver_email = $_REQUEST["Email__3"];
 /////////////////

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = "Hi .";

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = "abc@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "00000000";            // GMAIL password
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier


$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                       // 1 = errors and messages
                                       // 2 = messages only




$mail->SetFrom('abc@gmail.com', ' Global'); //sender's     email address

$mail->AddReplyTo("abc@gmail.com","Global"); //A reply to address

$mail->Subject    = "10% Off Voucher";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";     // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = $receiver_email; //receiver's address
$mail->AddAddress($address, $receiver_name); //name of receiver

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}



?>
```

Is it a problem with the hosting provider or something wrong with my code?

Comment: It works fine on my server. Are you using 000webhost Free Hosting or Paid?

Comment: Same code, I have tested on my XAMPP. It's work just fine.

Comment: Sorry people. Wrong box. Here's the comment:
000webhost is blocking Gmail. Are you using a free account? You will need to check with them to confirm, but I'm sure that's the issue.

Comment: @JakeGould it does actually. Free hosting does not give as much feature as paid hosting does. Even resources and other things are limited.

Comment: Am using the free version of 00webhost.  Yes it does work fine on my localhost (XAMPP) but fails to work once hosted.

So you guys think the issue is with the free version blocking it?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It could be that your host does not have OpenSSL extensions activated for Apache with PHP for some reason.

That said, you don’t really need SMTP to send mails. In fact the typical way one sends mails on a Unix/Linux host is via the local `sendmail` SMTP. Since you are using `PHPMailer` looking in the `examples/` folder in the `PHPMailer` repository [shows there is a `sendmail` example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/sendmail.phps). I wold recommend you use this instead of SMTP on your remote host:

```
require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// Set PHPMailer to use the sendmail transport
$mail->isSendmail();

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer sendmail test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Also, another way to check if your remote server at `000WebHost` is allowing access to Google’s TLS port is to use this script [found in this answer](https://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=13037596&sid=aa4cc83b488c6bc7b4e32e96a46067de#p13037596). Take this and place it in PHP file on your host & then load it in a web browser.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen('tls://smtp.gmail.com:465');
if(!$fp)
{
    echo 'Unable to connect';
}
else
{
    $response = fgets($fp, 256);
    echo 'Response: ' . $response;
}
?>
```

The success message I am getting is:

> Response: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP r14sm2233165qga.4 - gsmtp

If it fails the response would be something like this:

> Warning: fsockopen(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed:
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test.php on line 3

And if it fails, then you know there are issues with `000WebHost` and output TLS connections to Gmail.

Comment: yes that must be it because I also get the following error when using sendmail: 

     Mailer Error: Could not execute: /usr/sbin/sendmail

Comment: thanks! Sorry, I can't vote up your answer because I lack reputation apparently but thx for helping out.

I would need to find a another host(free) which might support sendmail at least.